# RecycleView Adapter notifyItemRangeInserted reload all rows after start position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to add a some new rows (items) in my `RecyclerView.Adapter`.
After I added them in the `ArrayList`, I'm calling `notifyItemRangeInserted(changeIndexStart, newItemsAdded);` where

```
changeIndexStart = is the index where the first element was inserted
newItemsAdded = how many new rows was inserted
```

So if I have some thing like:

```
mItems.add(item1); // position 0 
mItems.add(item2); // position 1
mItems.add(item3); // position 2 
mItems.add(item4); // position 3
```

If I add `mItems.add(2, item5); mItems.add(3, item6);` and call `notifyItemRangeInserted(2, 1);`all the items after position 2 will be refreshed (an animation is applied on them).

Is there a way that only my new rows to have the animation?

Answer (score 0):

i don't think , because animation will applied to all item in the recyclerview

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: oo sory, next time